# Win7 user folder is now desktop folder

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

O.P.
HI Everyone.
I installed a SSD drive recently and thought I would move all my user folders (eg Desktop, My Document, My Music etc) off to another drive.

To do this I right clicked on the respective folders, went to location and changed it to the new location.

HOWEVER...in the process, I've some how messed up my desktop folder location.

All the folders that were in my users directory are now appearing on my desktop ie My Documents, My Music etc.

When I right-click on my c:\users\username, and go to Properties, it gives me a Location tab (which I think it shouldn't) and it says on there "Files in the **Desktop folder** are rstored in the target locaiton below.... etc" So Windows is thinking that my c:\users\username directory is the Desktop ( c:\users\username\dekstop) directory.

When I double-click on the c:\users\username\desktop folder, it says "c:\users\username\desktop is not accessible. Access Denied"

I've tried clicking on Restoring to default — Access Denied.

I didn't so a restore point before doing any of this. 
Does this mean I have to delete this user profile and start all over again?
Hope not - that's a lot of setup.

Hope someone can help... that would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use "restore default" since your desired location **is not the default**.

I'd find out why access is denied. Right click and click security.

The permissions should be full permissions to the named account, *Administrators* (the group that is), and *SYSTEM*. The owner is, of course, the named account.